# How to include path using an eviornment variable in compile_flags.txt?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, clang, clangd

I am compiling with clang and editing with Visual Studio Code using the clangd extension on Windows. Compilation is fine, my issue is with intellisense.

I am using a compile_flags.txt that looks like this:

```
-I
src
-I
%VULKAN_SDK%/Include
-xc++
-std=c++17
```

The src include paths works but the vulkan include does not. I believe this is because I am using an environment variable, because if I explicitly write the full path out it works. I'd like to use the environment variable so I can use this same setup if I choose to work on Linux where the install path for Vulkan is different.

Is there a different syntax I need to use in order to use the enviornment variable in a path?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think compile_flags.txt supports environment variables.

My recommendations would be:

- Do not use compile_flags.txt, prefer compile_commands.json.

  - Rationale: Indexing the project only works with compile_commands.json.
- Do not hand-write the compile_commands.json, have your project's build generate it. If your build uses `make`, you can use [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear). Otherwise, see https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup for more options.

  - Rationale: Information about needed include paths and other flags is only in one place (the build files).
- Expansion of environment variables should be handled by your build system (e.g. `make` supports that, so do other build systems).

Comment: I don't use build systems. Thank you for the ideas though. I've decided to drop Windows and switched to GCC so this is not so much a problem anymore.

Comment: @CLearner How do you compile your code? Do you invoke `gcc` directly on the command line, typing out the `-I %VULKAN_SDK%/Include` flag each time?

Comment: I execute a bash script (bat file on Windows). The compilation flags are stored in the script as variables. These scripts can be executed as build tasks in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @CLearner The principle behind [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) is that it runs an executable command (such as a script), and records the compiler invocations that it (transitively) makes and their command-line arguments. So, it should be suitable as a way to generate a `compile_commands.json` based on your script. Granted, I've never used it with a Windows .bat file -- if that doesn't work out of the box, worth filing an issue!

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you.